# How can I set the units on multiple axis on Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a HighCharts graph of the data I am capturing on an Analog do Digital Converter (ESP32)

I am plotting the raw ADC data which is in the range 0-4095 but would also like to put on the right side of the graph the corresponding voltage. For each point the voltage is (ideally but not in reality) 3.3V times ADCmeasurement/4096.  I do not want to graph the data a second time just want a scale on the right that is in voltage.
So for example on the raw data of 1200,  I want the right side to be 3.3/4096*1200 = 0.997Volts

Here is my current Y axis code:

```
    yAxis: [{ // left y axis
    title: {
        text: 'RAW DAC Value'
    },
    labels: {
        align: 'left',
        x: 3,
        y: 16,
        // format: '{value:.,0f}'
    },
    showFirstLabel: false
}, { // right y axis
    linkedTo: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    opposite: true,
    title: {
      text: 'Voltage'
    },
    labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: +3,
        y: 16,
        // format: '{value:.,0f}'
    },
    showFirstLabel: false
}],
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to only format the second y-axis labels:

```
    yAxis: [{...}, {
        ...,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return 3.3 / 4096 * this.value
            }
        }
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gbhe64n1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: Just got back from a trip and tried this and it worked. Thanks so much for the Live Demo as that helped me be more sure of the syntax.

Will read the API Reference too!